# Why does my method predefine the argument `(num=nil)`?

Tags: ruby

Please explain what the purpose of `(num=nil)` on line 1 is. I am trying to replicate the `Enumerable` module and was taken aback by the `#count` method.

```
def my_count(num = nil)
   c = 0
   if block_given?
     my_each { |i| c += 1 if yield(i) }
   elsif num.nil?
     c = length
   else
     my_each { |i| c += 1 if i == num }
   end
   c
 end
```

Comment: It's a default value for the parameter

Comment: You should probably learn more ruby basics before trying to "replicate enumerable". A good book will provide better learning experience.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I following a learn Ruby curriculum at the moment and this is one of the exercises.

Comment: We cannot tell unless we know what `my_each` is.

Comment: my each is a replica of #each and functions exactly the same way.

Comment: Are you writing about your `each` (my `each`) or `my_each`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you define a method in Ruby, you can make it have arguments. When the method is called, the arguments are replaced by objects of your choosing. When you define an argument in the method definition, it becomes the default value.

For example, if you simply call `my_count` in a program, it will automatically choose `num` to be `nil`, since no argument was explicitly provided. Otherwise, if you called `my_count(5)`, then `num` in the method will be 5.

Here is another example, with the default value as an empty hash. I will create two `Server` objects:

```
class Server
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :files

  def initialize(name, files={})
    @name = name
    @files = files
  end
end

# Supply hash of files
Server.new('hostname', {'filename' => '2015-08-21 13:49 -4000'})

# New server will have no files -- empty hash
Server.new('hostname')
```

Let's change the `initialize` method and create one last server:

```
class Server
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :files

  def initialize(name, files)  # No default value for files
    @name = name
    @files = files
  end
end

Server.new('hostname', 'path/to/files/')
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

In the modified class, I only supplied 1 argument, the name. Because `files` no longer has a default value, then not including the argument raises an error. To clarify, omitting an argument is only allowed when the method definition has a default value for the argument. Without a default value, nothing will be used (not `nil`, `0`, or `''`), and the program will stop/crash -- an error has been raised/encountered.

It is possible to create a method without arguments. Here is an example using `String#length`. You will see that `.length` does not take an argument, and instead works on the string.

```
string = 'Hello, world!'
string.length
# => 13
```

Comment: In effect you MUST specify whether no argument is present (since in the original #count source code it initializes with a parameter) contrary to JavaScript where it performs this "nil" assignment automatically?  Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: Not exactly. Sometimes a method does not need an argument. Take `String#length`. It does not take an argument -- it is called as `'Some String'.length` and the length is calculated from there. It is an instance method. Now, since you are designing `my_count` to take an argument, you are saying this: "If I just call `my_count`, then `num` will be `nil`. Otherwise, if I supply it with `5`, then `num` will be `5`." I am basically saying what I did above. Take a look at the `Server` examples again, and take note of the error message (it is within a paragraph, not in its own block)

Comment: By indicating the default argument state (num = nil) I am by implication specifying that this method can take an argument.  Thank you so much for bringing me back down to earth on this one, embarrassing as it was for me.

Comment: Actually, the method _always_ takes an argument... If you do not explicitly choose an argument (like `my_count(5)`), then it will supply `nil` to the method, like so: `my_count(nil)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [`Enumerable#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) documentation you will notice that you can call count with no arguments, with an argument or with a block.

The 3 if-conditions in your code reflects these 3 different ways to call the method.

The reason you have `(num = nil)` is to provide the ability to omit the `num` parameter when calling `count`. In no explict value for `num` is given, then it defaults to `nil` (and it will fall into the second if-condition `num.nil?`).

Comment: I read the documents and was initially confused at the three choices.  If a block is provided, the yield portion kicks into effect - piece of cake.  If a bloc is not provided, it... goes straight into enumerating the elements that return true?  What would be the thrid example, that of an argument? What sort of argument would I pass to #count? I must not be wrapping my head around how methods accept parameters.  I looked at blocks procs and lambdas as the "parameters" of the Ruby world (I'm coming from JavaScript).